# Ontology over time

Tags: reference-request, ontology, time

Looking for any recommended references for this topic, I was recommended a good book on logic previously on here, and found it extremely enlightening, mainly how we deal with issues like the ship of theseus problem, there is many good references on ontology however I am searching for one that gives some treatment to temporal problems.

Comment: You should always start with SEP: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/time/.

Comment: Huw Price is the best combination of comprehensiveness and understandability imo for the big 3 “aspects” of time: the idea of the present, the passage of time, and its direction.  https://uberty.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Huw-Price-Times-Arrow1997.pdf

Comment: Old lady to old lady: Am I going up or am I coming down? 

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what "the same treatment" means, but on my reading list is [*The Ontology of Time* (GB)](https://books.google.com/books?id=Mat6NarkYXsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=ontology%20time&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjskbqR58r9AhVFj4kEHZHJAm8Q6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=ontology%20time&f=false) by Oaklander which is [repeatedly cited in WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?go=Go&search=l.%20nathan%20oaklander&ns0=1) in philosophically minded articles. L. Nathan Oaklander is a retired, contemporaneous philosopher here in the Midwest, and I poked through the book, and it looks like it might help to have some reading in general ontology to which I would have read and would recommend [Berto and Plabani's *Ontology and Metaontology* (GB)](https://books.google.com/books?id=Jy3bBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=meta-ontology%20and%20ontology&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYmInp6Mr9AhXxkIkEHQWSC0gQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=meta-ontology%20and%20ontology&f=false).